# Importing local maven apk dependency

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

Using Android Studio I have Project A and Project B. Project B is a library that is built into an APK file and stored into my maven server and distributed to everyone who uses it. Not sure if that is the best route to take or make it into a jar file. (opinions requested on that matter)

So I need Project A to use Project B as a dependency through the build script instead of manually importing Project B into Project A for every computer who uses it.

below is currently what I have for a build script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'group:name:version'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("")
            storePassword ""
            keyAlias ""
            keyPassword ""
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/main/java']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

But I do end up getting a Failed to find: group:name:version

And yes for privacy purposes I have replaced my actual info with group:name:version
Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. I did not have the full group name.